# Como criar um campo de calendario em PHP ou Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, data

Preciso do seguinte, ter um calendário aberto (*se possível já vir com as datas de ontem pra trás bloqueadas*) para fazer agendamento de serviço, quando clicar na data `X`, aí vou jogar essa data em um `input`.

Não sei como criar esse campo de data, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: jquery datepicker

Comment: Obrigado, consegui, usei esse: http://jsfiddle.net/KRFCH/ sabe como faço para alterar para portugues? as datas estão nido em ingles

Comment: já tentou usar o input type date do html5?

Comment: consegui http://www.devmedia.com.br/calendario-em-jquery-criando-calendarios-com-datepicker/37458

Comment: Da uma olhada na documentação do datepicker que la tem como traduzir